# Move a set of data in a table in database to another database into the same table without losing data in the destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table called conditions on my main database and on archive database.

During archive process 20 of the values in the table were moved to archive database.
I need those 20 values to be back on main database without losing the data on main database table.

Table name: Conditions
Database names : Main_DB and Archive_DB

Comment: Ok... so just go ahead and do that? Or if you have an issue, please edit your question and describe it.

Comment: Also, please Dont write random Words with Upper Case letters. It's pretty Annoying to Read text Like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into Main_DB.dbo.Conditions 
select * from Archive_DB.dbo.Conditions a
where not exists
(
select * from Main_DB.dbo.Conditions b where b.primarykeycolumn=a.primarykeycolumn)
)
```

Comment: I am getting error " Column name or supplied values doesn't match table definition". There are 82 Columns in the Table

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the solution. You need to use your primary key column or any unique comvination of column instead of primarykeycolumn. Please share uour table definition if you face any difficulties.